# Issue with C_TaskQuest.GetQuestInfoByQuestID(questID)

Tags: lua, world-of-warcraft

I'm practicing making an addon for World of Warcraft. I'm trying to display quest titles by retrieving the information from Wow's API and displaying in a frame. I can display if the quest has been completed or not just fine, but when I attempt to use the `C_TaskQuest.GetQuestInfoByQuestID(questID)` endpoint; nothing gets printed to the screen.

```lua
local function questStatus()
    for questID = 1, #array do
        local y = topY - (questID * 15 - 20)
        local fontString = UIConfig:CreateFontString(nil, "ARTWORK")
        fontString:SetFont("Fonts\\ARIALN.ttf", 13, "OUTLINE")
            fontString:SetText(C_TaskQuest.GetQuestInfoByQuestID(array[questID]))
            fontString:SetPoint("TOPLEFT", topX, y)
    end
end
```

the error I get in the chat frame is

```
7x Usage: local questTitle, factionID, capped, displayAsObjective = C_TaskQuest.GetQuestInfoByQuestID(questID)
[string "=[C]:"]: in function 'GetQuestInfoByQuestID'
[string "@My-Addon\Core.lua"]:66: in main chunk
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`C_TaskQuest.GetQuestInfoByQuestID()` only returns proper values for world quests but you can use [C_QuestLog.GetQuestInfo](https://wow.gamepedia.com/API_C_QuestLog.GetQuestInfo)() instead. Note that the data still has to be cached, the first time it won't be available until the `QUEST_LOG_UPDATE` event

See https://www.townlong-yak.com/framexml/go/QuestUtils_GetQuestName

Comment: But doesn't the quest log endpoint rely on the players quest log, and knowing the index of the quest in question?

Comment: `C_QuestLog.GetQuestInfo()` can be used on any quest id, it doesn't require having the quest in the quest log

Comment: interesting. I must've been more tired than I thought, the other night :P I'll test this and update when I get home :D

Comment: On second thought, that error also seems to imply you are not passing any quest id to `C_TaskQuest.GetQuestInfoByQuestID()`

Comment: Ya it's wierd. Bc I can use the iteration to show true or false if the quest has been completed using `IsQuestFlaggedCompleted(questID)`

Answer (score 1):

As shown in line one of the error;
**C_TaskQuest.GetQuestInfoByQuestID(questID)** will return all of these values: 
*questTitle*, *factionID*, *capped*, *displayAsObjective*

You have to pick a value to set as it can not set text for this return type, a list, which includes multiple values. It is the first returned, but it will also return the other values afaik.

I assume you want *questTitle*, so to get that without using additional function like **select()**, you would comment(or remove) your **SetText** line and use one of these 2 instead:

```
local questTitle, _, _, _ = C_TaskQuest.GetQuestInfoByQuestID(array[questID]) -- get quest title, other values to dummy locals
fontString:SetText(questTitle) -- set the text to the value of questTitle
-- fontString:SetText(C_TaskQuest.GetQuestInfoByQuestID(array[questID])) ORIGINAL


-- version using select(number, values)
fontString:SetText(select(1,C_TaskQuest.GetQuestInfoByQuestID(array[questID]))) -- set the text to the value of questTitle -- extra function usage is no good if done often!
```

Hope this helps!